# use of undefined type 'UTextBlock' UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I wrote a simple code and get an error, I can’t understand why there is no access

- C:\Users\79215\Documents\Unreal
  Projects\HowTo_UMG\Source\HowTo_UMG\MyUserWidget.h(37): note: see
  declaration of 'UTextBlock'
- C:\Users\79215\Documents\Unreal
  Projects\HowTo_UMG\Source\HowTo_UMG\MyUserWidget.cpp(15) : error
  C2027: use of undefined type 'UTextBlock'

MyUserWidget.h

```
    #pragma once


    #include "CoreMinimal.h"
    #include "Blueprint/UserWidget.h"

    #include "MyUserWidget.generated.h"


    /**
     * 
     */
    UCLASS()
    class HOWTO_UMG_API UMyUserWidget : public UUserWidget
    {
        GENERATED_BODY()

    public:
        virtual void NativeConstruct() override;

    public:


        UPROPERTY(BlueprintReadOnly, meta = (BindWidget))
        class UTextBlock* ItemTitle;
    };
```

MyUserWidget.cpp

```
#include "MyUserWidget.h"


void UMyUserWidget::NativeConstruct()
{
    Super::NativeConstruct();

    if(ItemTitle)
    {
        ItemTitle->SetText(TEXT("Name "));
    }
}
```

I added #include "Components/TextBlock.h" and get another errors

- C:\Users\79215\Documents\Unreal
  Projects\HowTo_UMG\Source\HowTo_UMG\MyUserWidget.cpp(13) :
  error C2664: 'void UTextBlock::SetText(FText)': cannot convert
  argument 1 from 'const char [1]' to 'FText'
- C:\Users\79215\Documents\Unreal
  Projects\HowTo_UMG\Source\HowTo_UMG\MyUserWidget.cpp(13): note:
  No constructor could take the source type, or constructor overload
  resolution was ambiguous
- C:\Program Files\Epic
  Games\UE_4.24\Engine\Source\Runtime\UMG\Public\Components/TextBlock.h(162):
  note: see declaration of 'UTextBlock::SetText'

Comment: As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/UMG/Components/UTextBlock/index.html), you're missing the include for `Components/TextBlock.h`.

Answer (score 1):

need to use FText

```
ItemTitle->SetText(FText::FromString("Name "));
```

and also include

```
#include "Runtime/UMG/Public/UMG.h"
or
#include "Components/TextBlock.h"
```